# Notepad++ find, replace etc

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I have a question regarding notepad++.
I have this text:

[image]

And this second one:

[image]

Basically I want to delete the countries that appear in image 2, from image 1. How can I do this?

Comment: don't put text in images. Paste a small sample so that people can try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this in Notepad++ as follows:

1. Use a normal Find & Replace to replace all the commas in List 2 with `,|`, so you end up with a list of countries to delete like `Country1,|Country2,|Country3,`.
2. Use this new list as the search term in a Regular Expression mode Find & Replace on List 1, with a blank as the replacement text.

Note that this assumes that country names are just separated by commas (no spaces).  The last entry in List 1 should also be followed by a comma, otherwise it won't get matched by the search.

Comment: note that `Country3` doesn't have a comma so you'll have a redundant comma where it was removed

Comment: Good spot @phuclv. I've updated my answer to correct this.

Comment: you also need to put a comma to the end of List 1, otherwise the last item won't be matched even if it's in the list

Comment: That's right - I put that in my earlier edit too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to automate your task in the Notepad++, but if your lists' data are not security critical, you can use script I have written in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RomanTarasiuk/ev0fzsog/. Or save the script text into a *.html file and open it in your browser – this way is completely secure, and my script is as simple as possible and cannot damage your computer/smartphone.

Format each of your two lists that each of them are placed in one line, values in them are separated by comma only (no spaces). Put your two lists into first and second textarea accordingly and press button, and your result list will be placed to the third textarea.